# How to access Parent class methods in subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Class 'X' is the Parent Class and Class 'Y' is the subclass of X. How can Class Y subclass get access to class X that is its parent class.

```
class x:
    def __init__(self,text):
      self.text = t

    def printThis(self):
        text = self.text
        print(text)

class y(x):

    def test():
        printThis(text)

a = y("printing")

a.printThis()
```

Comment: You probably want `def test(self): self.printThis()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can Class Y subclass get access to class X that is its parent class.

Python has multiple inheritance, so a class may have much more than one parent. All this his handled by the "mro" (method order resolution) and [the `super()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), that let you access methods from the "next" class in the mro.

Now note that in your code snippet, the real issue is not "accessing the parent class" at all, it's that you're trying to access a *global* "printThis" name - that is not defined. Python has no "implied this" like Java, you HAVE to use `self` to reference instance attributes or methods, so what you want is:

```
class Y(X):
    def test(self):
        self.printThis()
```

To illustrate this this has nothing to do with parent class, you'd have the same problem calling `printThis()` without `self` in the same class:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def printThis(self):
        print(self.text)

    def test(self):
       # this will fail just as well
       printThis()
```

Also, no need for `super()` here, Python will resolve `printThis` on the first class in the mro defining this name. You need `super()` when your subclass redefines a method of the parent class and still wants to call the parent's implementation, ie:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def printThis(self):
        print(self.text)


class Child(Example):
    def printThis(self):
        print("this is a test")
        super().printThis()
        print("test passed")
```

Answer (score -1):

in the y class init, you have to also init the parent class you want to inherit from.

```
class x:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

class y(x):
    def __init__ (self, #other vars here ):
        x.__init__(self, text)
        self.othervars = othervars

    def test():
        self.printThis(self.text)
```

Comment: If you're not doing anything in `__init__`, you can simply omit it.